# Application manifest must contain meta-data com.google.ar.core android sceneform AR

Tags: android, sceneform

I have used **Google Sceneform Tools(version1.12.0)** plugin for android ar. I have used **pixel 2 emulator in API level 29**. I shows bellow error

```
Error: Failed to create AR session
com.google.ar.core.exceptions.UnavailableException..........

 Caused by: com.google.ar.core.exceptions.FatalException: Application manifest must contain meta-data com.google.ar.core
```

But I have used bellow code..

1. In manifest file  i have used bellow code..

   ```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar" />
   <application
       ...
     <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

       <meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="required" />
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>

    </application>
   ```
2. I have used gadle file like bellow

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   apply plugin: 'com.google.ar.sceneform.plugin'
    android {
      compileSdkVersion 29
      buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
      defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.example.sceneform_ar"
      minSdkVersion 15
      targetSdkVersion 26           
      testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     }

    }

   dependencies {    
       androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
       implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.12.0'

      }

   sceneform.asset('sampledata/models/bear.fbx',
        'default',
       'sampledata/models/bear.sfa',
        'src/main/res/raw/bear')
   ```
3. In in activity xml I have used bellow code..

   ```
      <fragment android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"
       android:id="@+id/ux_fragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   ```
4. I have used bellow code in MainActivity

   ```
       ModelRenderable.builder()
           .setSource(this, R.raw.bear)
           .build()
           .thenAccept(renderable -> bearRenderable = renderable)
           .exceptionally(
                   throwable -> {
                       Log.e("Errror***** >", "Unable to load Renderable.", throwable);
                       return null;
                   });
   ```

   What is the wrong with it? I don't know. Can you please help me to solve the problem

Comment: It seems that AR element not downloaded. Like mobile vision it needs to download library inertly. So please check two things. 1. Use mobile data for first installation
and 2. Use meta data inside application tag not in activity tag

Comment: @TariqulIslam thanks sir, I have solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

Silly mistake I have used bellow code inside MainActivity

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="required" />
```

My manifest will be..

```
 <application
......">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="required" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```